# .NET DataGridView: Correct way of dealing with parsing errors while handling the CellParsing event?

Tags: .net, exception, parsing, datagridview, error-handling

I am currently developing an application for an angle measurement device (goniometer).
A `DataGridView` component is used for configuring nominal values (and tolerances) for the measured angles. The user shall be able to enter the angles in various ways, such as 2° (for degrees) or 120' (for minutes of arc) or 7200" (for arcseconds). For this I created a parser which will convert a valid string to the angular value (a double, in degree) or fail if the string is not valid.

As I understand the correct point of time to invoke the parser is during handling of the `CellParsing` event. **But how do I correctly handle the case when parsing has failed?**

According to MSDN sample code I get the idea that I should leave the `ParsingApplied` property of the `DataGridViewCellParsingEventArgs` (which is passed to the `CellParsing` handler) set to `false`. If I do this (and leave the `Value` property unchanged) a `FormatException` is thrown by conversion attempts that are then done by the framework which raises the `DataError` event.
Instead of a `FormatException` which contains a rather unspecific error message I would like to have an exception which contains information about the specific error which caused my parser implementation to fail so that I can show a specific error message in the `DataError` event. I assumed that I can throw a `FormatException` myself from within the `CellParsing` handler but this exception is not caught by the framework and thus does not result in raising the `DataError` event (in fact the outmost exception handler terminates the application).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DataGridView` data errors are a nightmare to get the hang of.
I've had to deal with this a lot recently, and in the end I just gave up and made my own implementation of `DataGridViewColumn` and `DataGridViewCell`. Doing so avoids all parsing errors, as you specifically handle it all yourself within your cell's `ParseFormattedValue` method.

My experience with all of this was turbulent but very worthwhile, as now I have a user interface that allows many different types of data to be input into a cell.

You can see some code I came up with to do this in a question I posted on MSDN [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformsdatacontrols/thread/0bc88019-4cd9-4232-b7aa-addf746c5e8e).
You can adapt that to match your own formatting (hopefully you can see what it's doing).

Comment: I hope it goes well for you. If you get any problems, don't hesitate to comment and I'll try help you with it. Good luck!